# jQuery questionnaire slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I am hoping to create a questionnaire on my Intranet that makes it simpler for the user by showing only one 'section' at a time, and allows the users to progress forwards and backwards through the form.

Rather than describe what I have in mind, I made a little GIF
[image: Slider]

I would really appreciate some advice on the best way to tackle this before I blindly stubmle into it. 
Some questions / thoughts

- Rather than re-invent the wheel, is there something out there that can already do this? (I couldn't find anything suitable)
- Would this be best done as one single HTML document with sliding DIVs or use AJAX to load each section somehow?
- Some questions require fairly long responses from the user. I would prefer the PREV and NEXT buttons to save their progress asynchronously to avoid lost time if they 'accidentally' close the form or whatever users tend to do.
- I am fond of jQuery so would probably prefer a jQuery solution

Any advice to help point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think `RhinoSlider` is exactly what you want:

Tutorial: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/create-multi-step-form-rhinoslider/

Demo: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/multi-step-rhino/

Comment: Many thanks. (the link to the tutorial should be http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/create-multi-step-form-rhinoslider/ ).
rhinoslider.com seems to be down at the moment, but it does indeed look like it can do what I'm hoping to achieve. I'll check back later

Answer (score 1):

you should try html5 rather. here is the link. hope it helps ...

http://slides.html5rocks.com/#controls-slide

Comment: Interesting site, thanks. There are two problems (1) I'd have to learn HTML5 ;)  (2) Our users are mostly IE8 and IE9. I gather they aren't so good at HTML5.  I will investigate further though, thank you